# How to read a float from a raw binary file written with numpy's tofile()

Tags: python, numpy, bitstring

I am writing a `float32` to a file with numpy's `tofile()`.

```
float_num = float32(3.4353)
float_num.tofile('float_test.bin')
```

It can be read with numpy's `fromfile()`, however that doesn't suit my needs and I have to read it as a raw binary with the help of the `bitstring` module.

So I do the following:

```
my_file = open('float_test.bin', 'rb')
raw_data = ConstBitStream(my_file)
float_num_ = raw_data.readlist('float:32')

print float_num
print float_num_
```

Output:

```
3.4353
-5.56134659129e+32
```

What could be the cause? The second output should also be `3.4353` or close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that numpy's `float32` is stored as little endian and bitstrings default implementation is bigendian. The solution is to specify little endian as the data type.

```
my_file = open('float_test.bin', 'rb')
raw_data = ConstBitStream(my_file)
float_num_ = raw_data.readlist('floatle:32')

print float_num
print float_num_
```

Output:

```
3.4353
3.43530011177
```

Reference on bitstring datatypes, [here](http://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/reading.html).

Comment: On a side note, `numpy`'s `tofile` writes in whatever the native endian-ness of the hardware/OS is.  Most things these days run on x86 hardware, so little-endian is the norm.  However, if you were running on a SPARC CPU, `numpy.tofile` would write in big-endian order.  `bitstream` probably chose big-endian because it's the default "network" order.  You might consider using the builtin `struct` module instead of `bitstream` (though bitstream has plenty of nice features).